# Is it possible to invoke "Select" method via reflection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I am working on a project and the situation I have encountered is that I need to "select" data from a queryable object. Unfortunately, I can not know what type that actual queryable object is at compile-time. So that I tried to invoke "select" method via reflection. The code I've tried so far is below.

```
....
.......
//suppose that I've got TSource and TResult at runtime.
Type argumentType = Model.GetArgumentType();

//get a queryable object from modle.
IEnumerable obj   = Model.GetQueryableObject(); 

//looking for Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector);
var selectMethod = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)
                  .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                  .Where(mi => mi.Name == "Select" &&                            
                               mi.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 2)
                  .Single()
                  .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { argumentType, argumentType });

//that is where I have no idea how to do it
var result = selectMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { obj, **xxxxxx** });
....
...
```

Can anyone tell me how can I make a "`Func<TSource, TResult>`" for the selectMethod to invoke "Select" method via reflection? Thanks.

**Update:**
As @Jon Skeet mentioned. There are several mistakes in example code. Apparently, I may asked the question in the wrong way (definitely it's all my fault). So that I decided to modify the original question to make it more clearly( or worse). Hope that helps.

Comment: What exactly do you want to have in that `Func`? What should it do?

Comment: Queryable is a static class. Did you mean IQueryable? And why are you using queryable at all if you're finding methods from Enumerable?

Comment: It would be something like `Type funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(argumentType, argumentType);` But it's a little strange that you want `TSource` and `TResult` to be the same. After that, call [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6) with your `funcType` and whatever "select function" you want to put into your new delegate.

Comment: The real situation I am struggling with is kind of complicated. The example code in the question just simplified. @JeppeStigNielsen's comment however gives me a clue. I will take time to try it out. It would be better if it were not only a comment but a candidate answer. Then I can vote it up.  :)

Comment: "Promoted" my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer was once only a comment.)

It would be something like

```
Type funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(argumentType, argumentType);
```

(In a real situation you probably woldn't want `TSource` and `TResult` to be the same.)

After that, call [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6) with your `funcType` and whatever "select function" you want to put into your new delegate.